# How to return mongodb ObjectId _id after insertOne with mongodb scala driver

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongodb-scala

If possible, I would like to return the ObjectId() generated by mongo after insertOne operation

```
 def insert(inputDocument : Map[String,Any], databaseName : String, collectionName : String, mongoClient : MongoClient)
  : Future[Completed] = {

    implicit val formats: DefaultFormats.type = DefaultFormats

    val createdAt = new Date()
    val createdAtUnix = System.currentTimeMillis()

    val insertJson = write( inputDocument ++ Map("createdAt" -> createdAt, "createdAtUnix" -> createdAtUnix))

    val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase(databaseName)
    val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection(collectionName)

    val insertDocument = Document(insertJson)
    collection
      .insertOne(insertDocument)
      .toFuture()

  }
```

If not possible, i know it is possible to generate one, but how to be sure it's unique ?

Comment: Not possible, generate ID on client side so client knows it.

Answer (score 0):

to get id of object which was inserted use:

```
collection.insertOne(e).head.map{_ => e._id.toHexString}
```

If you want to send your own id to mongo generate it and use `immutable.Document`, but with immutable document don't forget to always set `_id`.

to generate unique id you can use 'ObjectId.get()'